# Efficient way to loop on comparing string list element to a string list sub-element

Tags: python, string, list, intersection

I am currently struggling to find an efficient way to compare part of a string element attached to a list, to another string element. The current code computation is very long (1 hour with 4,8 millions elements in first list and 5000 elements in second one).

What I need to do: If 8 first characters of the first string element is equal to the full second element, a third list is updated with the full first element. Once it is found, we test another element of the first list.

Here is the code:

```
for first_element in first_List :
    for second_element in second_List:
        if first_element[:8] == second_element :
            third_List.append(first_element)
            break
```

I know those kinds of loops are not the best way to deal with very big lists. The number of `if` tests is really huge.
I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this.

I think intersection with sets won't work since I'm comparing a part of an element to a full one and I need to copy the full first element in a third list.

Do you have some suggestions or ideas please?

Comment: You might consider using sortedlist from package [blist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist) for the second list and skip the second loop by using `if first_element[:8] in second_sorted_List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
second_set = set(second_list)
third_list = [value for value in first_list if value[:8] in second_set]
```

Example:

```
>>> first_list = ['abcdfghij', 'xyzxyzxyz', 'fjgjgggjhhh']
>>> second_list = ['abcdfghi', 'xyzxyzxy', 'xxx']
>>> second_set = set(second_list)
>>> third_list = [value for value in first_list if value[:8] in second_set]
>>> third_list
['abcdfghij', 'xyzxyzxyz']
```

This should be much more efficient. 
The conversion of the list `second_list` into the set is `O(n)`.
There is one loop over `first_list` that is `O(n)`. The lookup in the `set`, i.e. `in second_set` is  `O(1)`.

Comment: Creating the `set` in the list comp would be slower than just checking the list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are right. Fixed. Creating the set is once is enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a hash set, or just [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) in python.
The nice thing about a hash set is that it can check if an element is in the set very fast (O(1)), in your case improving runtime by a factor of up to  5000 over the O(n) solution of iterating though the list every time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list whose elements are taken from the `first_List` provided that its initial part (8 characters) is present in the `second_List`:

```
third_List = [x for x in first_List if x[:8] in second_List]
```

This approach should be optimized by using `second_Set` instead of `second_List`:

```
second_Set = set(second_List)
```